# Quartz.Net Reduce Logging / Remove Specific Message Serilog

Tags: c#, .net-core, quartz.net, serilog

My .NET Core 3 implementation of Quartz.Net is logging the following message approximately twice per minute and I would like to remove it without affecting my applications other logs:

"Batch acquisition of 0 triggers"

```
2020-06-22 17:42:24.745 +01:00 - [MyApplication] - [Debug] - [Quartz.Core.QuartzSchedulerThread] Batch acquisition of 0 triggers
2020-06-22 17:42:53.689 +01:00 - [MyApplication] - [Debug] - [Quartz.Core.QuartzSchedulerThread] Batch acquisition of 0 triggers
```

Where `[MyApplication]` is populated by the `Source` property and `[Quartz.Core.QuartzSchedulerThread]` comes from the `SourceContext`.

Quartz.net logs this automatically and I seem to have no control over deciding to log it or not. My logs are filling up too quickly.

My **Appsettings.json** file is as follows:

```
"Serilog": {
"IncludeScopes": false,
"MinimumLevel": {
  "Default": "Debug",
  "Override": {
    "Microsoft": "Warning",
    "System": "Warning"
  }
},
"WriteTo": [
  {
    "Name": "File",
    "Args": {
      "path": "C:/Logs/my-app.log",
      "buffered": "true",
      "flushToDiskInterval": "00:00:10",
      "rollingInterval": "Infinite",
      "rollOnFileSizeLimit": "true",
      "fileSizeLimitBytes": 10485760,
      "retainedFileCountLimit": 90,
      "outputTemplate": "{Timestamp:yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.fff zzz} - {Source} - [{Level}] - [{SourceContext}] {Message}{NewLine}{Exception}"
    }
  },
  {
    "Name": "Async",
    "Args": {
      "restrictedToMinimumLevel": "Information",
      "configure": [
        {
          "Name": "Console",
          "Args": {
            "outputTemplate": "{Timestamp:yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.fff zzz} - {Source} - [{Level}] - {Message}{NewLine}{Exception}"
          }
        }
      ]
    }
  }
]
```

}

My **Program.cs** `main` initially configures the logger like this:

```
Log.Logger = new LoggerConfiguration()
            .ReadFrom.Configuration(configuration)
            .Enrich.FromLogContext()
            // set Source property, which we use in output formatting, to the name of the application
            .Enrich.WithProperty("Source", value: "MyApplication")
            .CreateLogger();
```

And later in my **Startup.cs**, when my services & settings have been registered Serilog is reconfigured as follows:

```
 public void Configure(IApplicationLifetime applicationLifetime)
    {
        SerilogLogger.Reconfigure(
            applicationName: "MyApplication",
            toFixedFile: !string.IsNullOrEmpty(_loggerSettings.LogFilePathFixed),
            fileName: _loggerSettings.LogFilePathFixed,
            fileSizeBytes: configuredLogFileSize * 1024 * 1024,
            minimalLevel: "Debug",
            outputTemplate: _loggerSettings.LogFormat);
    }
```

Where the `Reconfigure` extension method comes from a 3rd party dll built in another development department.

I have tried to add the following after the invocation of `Reconfigure`:

```
SerilogLogger.RefineConfiguration(x => x.MinimumLevel.Override("Quartz", LogEventLevel.Warning));
```

But it doesn't work because the actual source is `MyApplication`, and if I use "MyApplication" instead of "Quartz" I suppress all debug and information logs for the entire application.

Any ideas? With code examples please.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I have implemented a solution for this problem, there were two parts to the solution:

**1 -** [As pointed out to me in the Quartz google groups,](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/quartznet/Cjco_Ob9yrM) I was missing the following Serilog configuration from appsettings.json to define the correct logging level for Quartz:

```
"MinimumLevel": {
  "Default": "Debug",
  "Override": {
    "Microsoft": "Warning",
    "System": "Warning",
    "Quartz": "Warning"
  }
},
```

The configuration of `"Quartz": "Warning"` suppressed the `Debug` "Batch acquisition" messages from being logged.

And

**2 -** The invocation of both the `SerilogLogger.Reconfigure` and `SerilogLogger.RefineConfiguration` methods was completely unnecessary. I removed this. It was overwriting the config from point 1) above. All Serilog configuration should take place in my appsettings.

Answer (score 1):

A supplement to the accepted answer if Serilog configuration is set outside of appsettings.json (eg Program.cs) is:

```
Log.Logger = new LoggerConfiguration()
    // [other configs omitted]
    .MinimumLevel.Override("Quartz", LogEventLevel.Warning)
    .CreateLogger();
```